# how do i merge array values into single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add(string) array values into single array, I have three array values like below:

```
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 16 )
Array ( [0] => jan [1] => feb )
Array ( [0] => 2012 [1] => 2012 )
```

and now i want those array in single array like below:

```
Array ( [0] => 15-jan-2012 [1] => 16-feb-2012 )
```

So how can i do this in php.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: You may need custom code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this custom code: Too simple, just a loop to access each and every array with there index and store in an array.

```
$d = array(15, 16);
$m = array("jan", "feb");
$y = array (2012, 2012);

$final = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($d); $i++){
    $final[] = $d[$i]. "-" .$m[$i]. "-" .$y[$i];
}
print_r($final);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => 15-jan-2012 [1] => 16-feb-2012 )
```

you can do it using, [array_merge_recursive](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_merge_recursive), but has some difficulties.

[ONLINE DEMO](https://eval.in/646728)

Comment: Noman thanks.. you save my life, working perfectly which i want.

Comment: i was not able to find who gave the answer, i just checked that Noman edited so i thought Noman give the answer.. so might be i am wrong, you have given the answer so thanks a lot for help me

Comment: @SantoshKhatri, **#Noman** added the ONLINE DEMO to my answer and i approve his edit.

Comment: ok so now it is ok or something else i do for you. actually i  m new in stackoverflow. so once again thanks for support.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way, I am supposing that your each array has same length

```
$a = array ('15','16' );
$b = array ('jan','feb');
$c = array ('2012','2012');

$newArray = array();

for($i=0;$i<=count($a);$i++){
    $newArray = $a[$i]. "-" .$b[$i]. "-" .$c[$i];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: same answer. what's new ?

Comment: Its a quiescence i think

Comment: I set the some answer --', I didn't see yours until i posted mine !!

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom code like this one for example:

```
$arr = [];
$arr1 = [15, 16, 17, ...];
$arr2 = [jan, feb, ...];
$arr3 = [2012, 2012, ...];

for($i=0, $count = count($arr1); i<$count; i++)
{
    $arr[] = "$arr1[$i]-arr2[$i]-arr3[$i]";
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the required dates array, finally concat it using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). Something like

```
$arr1 = array(15, 16);
$arr2 = array('jan', 'feb');
$arr3 = array(2012, 2012);

$date = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
$dates = array(array_column($date, 0), array_column($date, 1));

$reqDate = array();
foreach ($dates as $dateVal) {
  $reqDate[] = implode('-', $dateVal);
}

var_dump($reqDate); //your required output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it all in one swoop like so:

```
$a = [15, 16];
$b = ['jan', 'feb'];
$c = [2012, 2012];
$dates = array_map(function($arr) {
    return implode('-', $arr);
}, array_map(null, $a, $b, $c)));
```